# "Eternal" Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to create an Azure Function that constantly listens for events from an IP Cam SDK.
Is it possible to do something like this? Or my process would be killed eventually?

```
while (true)
{
    new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: I'd use a webhook to trigger the event.

Comment: you can look at "always on" option in the azure app service plan within which you can create the function.

Answer (score 2):

Azure functions differ from traditional services in a way that they don't need to listen for events continuously.

They get invoked each time automatically by triggers

Most common trigger types are:

1. ServiceBus
2. HTTP call
3. Timer

And many others

Check the official documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings

Comment: To add, if your workload doesn't have a "trigger" that's supported by azure functions, then it's probably not the best fit for your workload.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.